# hash of request body in a ktor plugin

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to implement idempotent post plugin on ktor, as in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpapi-idempotency-key-header-00

For that I need to calculate some kind of hash sum on request content **in a plugin**. Is there a way to actually do it? Or plugins do not have access to the body?
For now I've implemented a custom POST method that more or less does it, but this approach doesn't seem to be very ktor-ish

I'm also using content negotiation plugin which complicates things even further

Comment: Could you please share the code for your current solution?

Comment: No, sorry. It's way too dirty.
Maybe I'll try to implement it better at some point